# What engineering problems needs to be solved to build a potato-peeling robot?

Tags: robotic-arm

OK, let's say we have a tech request for a robotic system for peeling potatoes, and a design is as follows:

1. One "arm" for picking up a potato and holding it, rotating when needed.
2. Another "arm" for holding a knife-like something which will peel the skin from the potato.
3. Arm picks up a potato from first container, holds it over trash bin while peeling, then puts peeled potato in second container.
4. For simplicity a human rinses peeled potatoes, no need to build automatic system for it.
5. In first iteration even 100% spherical peeled potatoes are OK, but ideally would be good to peel as little as possible, to minimize the wastes.

**Question:**
I know that we're very, very far away from building such a system. Nevertheless, what are the purely **technical** difficulties which needs to be solved for such a robot to be built?

**EDIT**

Let's assume we stick to this design and not invent something radically different, like solving the problem with chemistry by dissolving the skin with something. I know that the problem of peeling the potatoes is currently being solved by other means - mainly by applying friction and a lot of water.

This question is not about it. I am asking specifically about the problems to be solved with the two-arms setup using the humanlike approach to peeling.

Comment: Pretty sure this is already done in factories!

Comment: @BrianLynch It would be great to look at some videos/specs/documents about it. :)

Comment: Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyK02WTJ4W8, it's not a robotic arm approach, it's simply mass-production automation.

Comment: @BrianLynch I watched this video a long time ago. My question is not about how to peel potato in production scale. My question is about robotic arms performing humanlike actions. And peeling potatoes.

Comment: In my opinion you are talking about finding a problem for a solution, which is just plain bad engineering. Unless your robot is supposed to do a number of different actions, it is overkill to use robotic manipulators to do this. On top of that, having a robot use a knife to do it is also generally the wrong approach since there are much easier methods (that are way less expensive compared to making a robot do it like a human) -- see [this peeler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0cjy_owrR0).

Comment: If it is for an art project then okay, or if the whole point is that the robot should be able to walk into a regular kitchen and use those tools then okay. But that problem is way more general, and you will have to be looking at object recognition, compliant arm position/force control, probably machine learning, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are many difficulties to overcome.  As others have shown, this problem seems like it is well-suited for fixed automation rather than robotics.  I spent considerable time working on telerobotics in the 1980s, and you will be encountering many of the same issues we dealt with then.  Here are a few off the top of my head:

- presenting potatoes to the arm individually (or worse, trying to pick them from a bulk collection of potatoes)
- protecting from the starches, juices, dirt, and other contaminants that will be thrown around during the peeling process
- peeling potatoes that have bulges
- peeling potatoes that have concave and convex sections
- ensuring growing eyes don't interfere with the cutting
- repositioning the potato so you can peel the ends that you were holding when the main part of the potato was peeled
- change in friction characteristics between gripping the skin and gripping the already-peeled section
- dealing with the size differences (both in gripping and in cutting)
- controlling the force between the blade and the potato skin (you can't just program positions because of the size variability)
- sizing the cutting blade:  too large and you will either miss indented sections, or remove too large of the outdented sections; too small and your process time will suffer
- coordinating between the robot and the blade: how do you ensure your force is correct?  That is probably easiest to do at the blade.  But this means the position of the blade will change as it responds to varying forces, so the wrist might need to account for that.
- stability of your grasp (while leaving enough open space for the blade)

Comment: Great! Thank you! And that's just non-exhaustive list of purely mechanical problems, wow!

Comment: You're welcome.  I wouldn't cast those as purely mechanical problems.  I left them in the domain of the problem because the first thing you need to do is understand what the system is required to do in the problem domain.  Each of these has mechanical, electrical, controls, and software implications.

Comment: well, after a second thought, you're surely right.